# sharepoint hardware requirements

Tags: sharepoint

what hardware requirements do I need for installing sharepoint server 2007?
How many servers do I need?
what properties each server should have?

Comment: Big ones, 42 of them.....

Comment: You'll need to answer a bunch of questions before that can be answered.  How many users?  How much data?  How frequently will the data be accessed?  Changed?

Comment: I would expect that Microsoft would have published information on minimum and recommended specs, which gives you a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer really depends on what the purpose of installation.

It IS possible to install a single-server farm (either in basic or advanced mode) on a desktop PC with Pentium IV 3GHz and under 1GB RAM, but hey, what will you expect it to do for you?

Here are some of the  questions that should be addressed:

- How many people do you want to serve?
- What amounts and types of information do you intend to process and in what ways?
- What response rates do you strive to provide over what channel types for different requests your users will submit?
- What are the security restrictions regarding access to database, web services and object model?
- Will you publish your portal(s) through ISA Server or another proxy?
- Do you plan to deploy Development/Testing/User Acceptance/Staging/Production farms?
- How critical is the availability of your information and what is your disaster recovery plan?

and one more question:

- can you use a hosted deployment to avoid managing hardware and the platform?

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815104825/http://geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/10/17/116101.aspx) goes into great detail on what kind of hardware you need for MOSS 2007, depending on your usage requirements.